# Find the first three terms in the local behavior as $x \to 0+$ of a particular solution of $x^3y''+y=x^{-4}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I'm assuming I need to use the Method of Dominant Balance to solve this question. Using the substitution $y = e^{S(x)}$, I get $$x^3(e^S S'' + (S')^2e^S) + e^S = x^{-4}$$

In the past, the RHS = 0 and I'd be able to cancel out the $e^S$ terms and go on my way. I'm not sure what to do here and my textbook doesn't have any examples to follow.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problems, first find the local behavior of the general solution of $$x^3y''+y=0$$
Then you need to add the particular solution. Since the right hand side is the form $x^{-m}$, the solution will be a sum of terms $$y_p=\sum_nc_nx^{-n}$$
Taking the second derivative yields $$y''_p=\sum_n n(n+1)x^{-(n+2)}$$
Plug this in the differential equation and you get $$\sum_nc_n\left(n(n+1)x^{-n+1}+x^{-n}\right)=x^{-4}$$
It is easy to see that the lowest power term is $n=4$.
$$y_p=c_0+c_1x^{-1}+c_2x^{-2}+c_3x^{-3}+c_4x^{-4}$$
Identify the coefficients, see if the homogeneous solution has relevant powers, and you have your answer.